# Number of read and write ports on L2 and L3 cache

Tags: processor, cache, intel

I have an Intel Core i9-9900K processor (some specs [here](https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i9/Intel-Core%20i9%20i9-9900K.html)) and I'm trying to figure out how many read and write ports each level of cache has, for a personal project. I cannot find this in any online literature.

The one value I have found is that the L1 cache has 3 ports: 2 read and 1 write. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I found the port number for some older CPU online here https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/write-back-policy

At TABLE 6.3. Intel Itanium-2 Cache Hierarchy Specifications:

L2 cache has 4 read, 4 write port and L3 only have 1 r/w port
[image: screenshot]
[image]

Maybe you can use the number as a reference.

Comment: That is a 20 year old CPU, and not even an x86 one.